# Excel to latex for mac 2016

Tags: mac, excel2latex

Does anyone know if there is an excel to latex converter for mac (El Capitan) with excel 2016.

Comment: I suggest a combination of datatool, longtable which can be used to work with csv files. Excel should export tables very easy.

Comment: Is it raw data you are exporting or do you need to preserve (complex) formatting? Raw data are much easier to export.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you use TeXShop as your editor, you can do `Macros > Past Spreadsheet Cells`. This is just a built-in version of Alan Munn's [`csv2latex` Applescript](http://ctan.org/pkg/csv2latex), which could be used with any editor on a Mac.

Comment: I often write string formulas in Excel to generate LaTeX tabular code.  Excel formulas like `=A1&"&"&TEXT(B1,"hh:mm:ss")&"&"&TEXT(C1,"0.000")&"\\"` will generate rows that can then be copy-pasted into the TeX file. This gives good control over output formatting, but is only semi-automated.  It is also portable, as only Excel is needed.

Comment: You can use easily http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables. Tables generator on line.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit tricky, I found it incidentally after long searching.

1. run the excel2latex makro you can download here:  http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/excel2latex/Excel2LaTeX.xla
2. press the little arrow in the very top of excel to add a command to your symbol menu bar
3. Go to 'more commands'
4. Select Makros
5. Add LATEX to you menu bar

It is shown as a white circle but acts as the normal excel2latex command from 'Extras' in the previous versions

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/helotpl/cliptable app converts table to latex inside clipboard. It works best with tables copied from Apple's Numbers (retains some formatting), but also works with Excel but without formatting (at this moment).
App is downloadable from appstore with minimal charge (tier1), this is still not enough even to cover my charges for developer account.
Appstore link: https://apps.apple.com/pl/app/cliptable/id1540973595?l=pl&mt=12

Comment: -2 score because of "first post" and "late answer", this post is pretty unresolved and possibly most people find it via search before they ask this question. Still hope this answer will help somebody.

Comment: The downvotes are I think because as-written this is borderline spam. As it's a tool you've written, that should be up-front. Something like 'I am the author of a tool called XXX which ...'